# How to Track the Tabs in a Page in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, web, event-tracking

I have been searching and could not find a comprehensive answer

I have a website which is tracked in google analytics, I have a page in it which contains the Tab(Bootstrap tab which hide and show tab on click), how exactly I can track when the user clicked on the tab, it should be tracked in the google analytics

**The main page is tracked but how can i track the tabs inside the page**

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Google Tag Manager](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/tag-manager/) integrated with your site (if you don't, you should), you can set up a Tag triggered on the tab click.

There are many ways to set up such a trigger, and this depends on your markup - you can target the element via id, CSS class, etc.

In your Tag, you should select 'Track Type' of Event, and specify Category/Action/Label which make sense for your Google Analytics setup. For example (Category: FAQ Link Clicks, Action: "Tab Opened", Label: Tab Title (variable)).

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an `onclick` event that will fire a custom event for your Analytics snippet.

An example:

```
<a href="#contact" onclick="FireEvent('ContactButton');"></a>
```

If you use Analytics.js

```
function FireEvent(event){
    ga('send', 'event', event); 
}
```

If you use gtag.js

```
function FireEvent(event){
    gtag('event', event);
}
```

You can of course delete that function, is there just as decoration.